# Android webview chromium "WARNING:proxy_service.cc" and "WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc"

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I'm struggle with a strange issue. I'm trying to load a https web page.
My webView get the following logs and the webview doesn't load my url or load but not show.

```
W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
```

Thanks.

Comment: Those warnings can be safely ignored. Have you tried loading other https urls, and other http urls into your WebView?

Comment: yes, I  tried. I think so these ignored but these logs are only diffirence between other https logs.

Comment: I solved my problem and these log is not effect my webview. Those warnings can be safely ignored.